# SELECT DISTINCT omitting columns present in ORDER BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I have a `SELECT DISTINCT...` query that produces following output:

```
       id       |      name      |     _pref_     | _num_ 
----------------+----------------+----------------+-------
 Cf-1           | Cf-1           | Cf-            |     1
 Cf-2           | Cf-2           | Cf-            |     2
 Cf-3           | Cf-3           | Cf-            |     3
 Cf-5           | Cf-5           | Cf-            |     5
 Me-1           | Me-1           | Me-            |     1
 Me-2           | Me-2           | Me-            |     2
 Me-3           | Me-3           | Me-            |     3
 Me-4           | Me-4           | Me-            |     4
 Me-5           | Me-5           | Me-            |     5
 Me-6           | Me-6           | Me-            |     6
 Me-7           | Me-7           | Me-            |     7
 Me-8           | Me-8           | Me-            |     8
 Me-9           | Me-9           | Me-            |     9
 Me-10          | Me-10          | Me-            |    10
 Me-11          | Me-11          | Me-            |    11
 Me-12          | Me-12          | Me-            |    12
 Me-13          | Me-13          | Me-            |    13
 Me-14          | Me-14          | Me-            |    14
 Me-15          | Me-15          | Me-            |    15
 Me-16          | Me-16          | Me-            |    16
 Me-18          | Me-18          | Me-            |    18
 Me-20          | Me-20          | Me-            |    20
 Me-22          | Me-22          | Me-            |    22
 Me-24          | Me-24          | Me-            |    24
 RC-1           | RC-1           | RC-            |     1
 RC-2           | RC-2           | RC-            |     2
 RM             | RM             | RM             |      
 Ronda Hospital | Ronda Hospital | Ronda Hospital |      
(28 rows)
```

*_pref_* and *_num_* are just calculations over *name* column that let me order rows in a more intuitive way from user point of view.

But **they add no additional information** so I would remove them from the output.

The problem is that when I attempt to do so I get following error:

```
joanmi@alpha:~/.../SQL/gis$ node layer.carreteres_menorca.sql.js list | pg geogps
ERROR:  para SELECT DISTINCT, las expresiones en ORDER BY deben aparecer en la lista de resultados
LINE 43:         order by _pref_, _num_, nom
```

I know I could just wrap it again in another CTE or use it as a subquery and then order by a column but it seems to me that it's not the right solution...

I'm sure there should be some way to tell Postgres that those columns are dependent on the other ones so they can be omitted from the output even using DISTINCT clause.

The query producing former output is this:

```
WITH layer as (
    select
        computed.name as id
        , computed.name || '-' || id as part_id
        , computed.name as name
        , label
        , name as codiTram
        , ST_AsEWKT(geom) as geom
        , regexp_replace(
            name
            , '^([^0-9]+).*$'
            , '\1'
            , 'i'
        ) as _pref_
        , nullif(
            regexp_replace(
                name
                , '^[^0-9]*([0-9]+)?.*$'
                , '\1'
                , 'i'
            )
        , '')::integer as _num_
    from "Carreteres_Menorca"
    , lateral (
        select regexp_replace(
            name
            , '^.*?Me[-.]*([0-9]+).*$'
            , 'Me-\1'
            , 'i'
        ) as name
    ) as computed
    where name is not null
)
select distinct
    id, name, _pref_, _num_
from layer
order by _pref_, _num_, name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the results that you want if you `group by id, name`:

```
select id, name
from layer
group by id, name
order by max(_pref_), max(_num_), name
```

Comment: Amazingly simple!! :LOL: Thanks!

Comment: I won't. Its just that I haven't tested it yet. It seems really stright to me, but I answered from my smartphone and still didn't actually tested it. Tomorrow I will.

Comment: (won't _forget_, I mean…)